Piechart in R, borders too pointy on the inside
I'm making a piechart using ggplot2 and it looks fine in RStudio:
data <- data.frame(
  continent=c("Europe", "N. America", "S. America", "Asia", "Africa", "Australia"),
  value=c(80, 30, 20, 110, 40, 5)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=continent)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="black")+
  coord_polar("y") +
  theme_void() 
ggsave("piechart.png")

However, when I open the saved picture, you can see that the center has an unwanted spike from the green segment:

I feel this looks rather bad. Can I remove it somehow? Maybe change the line thickness so this is not as pronounced?

I am no {ggplot2} expert. Is it due to the size you use to save the plot? Have you played around around with the size arguments in ggsave? (On my machine) it defaults to > ggsave("piechart.png") Saving 8.85 x 4.46 in image.

I've tried using different sizes, and larger sizes do help a little. But it's mainly because the pointy spike seems proportionally smaller. I'd like to avoid the problem altogether, since it seems the lines are drawn longer than they need to be.

If you set the width to default 0.9, there is no issue, why are we setting it to 1?

The issue persists with width = 0.9 or omitting width

Edit
Setting the linejoin to 'bevel' helps w/o fiddling around with inner radius as in previous approach:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=continent)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="black",
           linejoin = 'bevel'
           )+
  coord_polar("y") +
  theme_void() 


You could use coord_radial instead of coord_polar, prevent axis expansion and set a minute inner radius:

    ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=continent)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="black")+
      coord_radial('y', expand = FALSE, inner.radius = 0.01) +
      theme_void()




You still have the green bar edge issue there.

Thank you. The inner radius needs some trial & error to maneuvre between spike and hole.

Thank you, using "bevel" works beautifully!
